# Stripping Html tags from Rss feeds using Feedzilla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

I cant seem to find info anywhere on how to strip html tags from the summary/title/etc fields of rss feeds using Feedzirra.

Here is my code:

```
# Get feed details
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(rssUrl)

  feed.entries.each do |entry|

    logger.debug("ENTRY.SummaryWithHtmlTags = #{entry.summary}")

  end
```

Any ideas how to strip the html tags from fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm learning so maybe I'm missing something but can't you do this?

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

# Get feed details
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(rssUrl)

  feed.entries.each do |entry|
    stripped_summary = strip_tags(entry.summary)
    logger.debug("ENTRY.SummaryWithHtmlTags = #{stripped_summary}")

  end
```